# unable to open website in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I want to open the following link in WebView

https://hrms.onlinesbi.com/irj/portal

I am using following settings on webview to do that

```
       WebSettings webSettings = mBrowserView.getSettings();
       webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //enable zoom control
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        //TODO : just for test
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

but not able to open [this](https://hrms.onlinesbi.com/irj/portal) website in webview, unable to understand what is the issue with this website bcus others websites working without any issue.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Some thing wrong with this site

Comment: @JhamanDas sorry due to some restriction unable to post complete code.

Comment: is there any error??

Comment: @NiravRanpara-  mBrowserView is my webview, check first line

Comment: put complete code first

Comment: Post full code your web view activity

Comment: also check the same issue with open source browser https://github.com/austindavidbrown/WebView-Developer-Browser

Comment: download browser from play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webviewbrowser&hl=en & find the same issue

Comment: @DemoMail - no error shown by my webview,  but when open same link in opera mini it shows "Could not open iView. The iView is not compatible with your browser, OS or device. Contact your system admin for more info."

Comment: are you displaying link in your webview or asking user to select any installed browser??

Comment: displaying link in my webview.